# Android project references multiple library project with Application classes

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I have an existing android app which references a jar file containing a class that extends android.app.Application.

Within the app manifest the application:name tag points to this jar file class.

Now i wish to add a reference to a new library project in the existing project. But the library project also has a class that extends android.app.Application. Now i am unable to set the manifest tag application:name again.

Please suggest what would be the correct solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chose exactly one of the two apps as your main app. You can't have both because Java does not support diamond inheritance.

Comment: I agree. The only solution for me was to modify the application class for my library project. I made the class singleton and passed the application instance of the calling app as a parameter within the class.